# React route gives unauthorized on heroku while working in development

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, react-router

I am working on React app using express in backend, and I deployed it on Heroku.
Now its working well except 1 route which gives me *unauthorized* message

[My Heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plYOn.png)

And this route is working on development mode.
Also I checked the token of the user in the localStorage and its already there.

Anyone has any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem after asking a friend of mine.

The problem was there was a conflict in routes between frontend and backend, so I added `/api/` to backend routes and to the frontend baseUrl.

**Ex**:

in backend I was using the routes like `app.use("/topic", topicRoutes);`

in frontend my baseUrl was `localhost:3000`

**To fix my problem**, I changed the routes:

`app.use("/api/topic", topicRoutes);`

`localhost:3000/api/`

Hope it helps someone :))